# React can't figure out why I am getting too many re-renders error

Tags: reactjs

This question has been asked a lot of times but each case is unique. So, I can't find what causes the error in my code. It looks like its related to the ternary on the return statement but I don't understand whats wrong.

```
const Results = () => {
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [summoner, setSummoner] = useState("");
  const location = useLocation();
  try {
    setSummoner(location.state.params);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fetch(
        "...",
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: summoner,
        }
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((favs) => setFavorites(favs));
      setLoading(false);
    })();
  }, []);

  return summoner.length > 0 ? (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Loader>
        <LoaderPosition>
          <DotLoader color={"white"} size={250} loading={loading} />
        </LoaderPosition>
      </Loader>
      <Favorites>
        <Title>Favorite Champions of {summoner}</Title>
        {Object.entries(favorites).map((entry) => (
          <Card key={entry[1].name} data={entry[1]} />
        ))}
      </Favorites>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Search />
  );
};

export default Results;
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to prevent going to `/results` by changing the URL from the address bar. Because if the search page does not send the required parameters, it throws an error.

Comment: You can not do `setSummoner` in your component scope, you have to call that in useEffect or in some function call. otherwise it will get called everytime your component is getting updated and it will go in infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
try {
    setSummoner(location.state.params);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

If you don't catch an error, you setSummoner over and over again. Each set re-renders the component, so you end up with an endless loop.